# MYSQL , millisecond loging ,OS:windows 2012,deep issue

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, logging

I hope any  MYSQL hero can help me ..

problem details :

I want to log slow query as a table in database not a log file that’s was working good but with one issue , I put log query time .05 sec. then the change bring only the queries exceed that time but without millisecond, the server bring it and log it like this 00:00:00 which I cannot use as good indicator to observe the query log time exactly !

Then I did a small thing though that maybe will solve it but it didn’t  , I change the query_time variable in slow_log table to accept 4 char length which the server accept but without any value like this :

00:00:00:0000

Seem the server did not record the millisecond that’s why bring it empty .

Kindly ,suggest me any modifications that maybe will help to solve this issues .
Mysql Version: 5.6.21 .
OS :Windows 2012 R2

Best Regard's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is [a limit of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html):

> The slow query log consists of SQL statements that took more than
>   long_query_time seconds to execute and (as of MySQL 5.1.21) required
>   at least min_examined_row_limit rows to be examined. The default value
>   of long_query_time is 10. Beginning with MySQL 5.1.21, the minimum is
>   0, and the value can be specified to a resolution of microseconds. For
>   logging to a file, times are written including the microseconds part.
>   **For logging to tables, only integer times are written; the microseconds part is ignored.** Prior to MySQL 5.1.21, the minimum
>   value is 1, and the value for this variable must be an integer.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Burhan , I will mark your answer accepted in 2 days if no one comment about that specially in new version of Mysql 5.7 or 6 maybe. Thanks again .

Comment: In 5.7 its [the same situation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html).